# Rails 3 - Query result to Map for jQuery Array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm sure this is a stupid bug that I'm missing but I can't seem to get past this issue.  I have a Query that selects two values Status and Count of items in that status.  Query works fine it is mapping these results into a jQuery data: block.  Here is what I have

This works

```
 data: [
           <% count_by_status.each do |c| %>
               ["<%= c[0] %>",<%= c[1] %>],
           <% end %>
     ]
```

This does not because the " " around status is turning into `&quot;`

```
<%=  count_by_status.map{|status, count| [status, count.to_i] }.inspect %>
```

I'm sure it is a stupid error but if anyone can help.  I have tried .html_safe, different formats..etc and it just keeps failing.

The ugly code works but the clean nice code doesn't..argh

**UPDATED** Still not sure why this works and the other actually escapes the code but this one works now

```
<%=  raw count_by_status.map{|status, count| [status, count.to_i] }.inspect %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails 3 escapes HTML unless you use pass it to the raw method or call the string's html_safe method.